# Lista vacia al momento de renderizar plantilla en flask

Tags: python, flask

**Al momento de imprimir la lista me la retorna vacia a pesar de que si hay clientes conectados, lo sé porque los imprimo antes.**

```
clientes_conectados = []
```

**Aqui inicia un servidor en donde llegan los clientes**
def iniciar_servidor():
global clientes_conectados

```
    ip_address = "0.0.0.0"
    puerto = 8080

    # Crear el socket del servidor
    tcp_listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_listener.bind((ip_address, puerto))
    tcp_listener.listen()

    print(f"Servidor escuchando en {ip_address}")

    while True:
        # Esperar por la conexión de un cliente
        cliente, direccion = tcp_listener.accept()
        clientes_conectados.append(cliente)
        print(f"Cliente conectado desde {direccion}")

        # Iniciar un hilo para manejar la comunicación con el cliente
        threading.Thread(target=manejar_cliente, args=(cliente,)).start()
```

**Retorna los clientes y los añade en una etiqueta select en html**

```
@app.route('/clientes_conectados')
def obtener_clientes_conectados():
    return render_template('Actualizaciones.html', clientes=clientes_conectados)
```

**Etiqueta html a donde se deberian mostrar**

> {% for cliente in clientes %}
>             {{ cliente }}
>         {% endfor %}

Comment: El error puede ser por muchas cosas. Podrías proporcionarnos un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ubicar más facilmente el error por favor?